# Reload UITableView from Controller

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, swift2

I have `classVC`, an UIViewcontroller containing an UITableView and some other stuff.

I have `classTVC` being an UITableViewController.

In `classVC` in instantiate `var TVC = classTVC()`

Then I programatically set the *delegate* and *datasource* of my UITableView to `TVC`.

**The problem :**

In the controller `TVC` I declare the following method :

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Destructive, title: "Delete") { (action, indexPath) in
        // delete item at indexPath
    }
    let share = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "Disable") { (action, indexPath) in
        // share item at indexPath
    }

    share.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

    return [delete, share]
}
```

**How to reload the UITableView after `share` or `delete` actions had been executed? It happen in the UITableViewController so I can't call `.reloadData()`**

I already tried to retrieve parentViewController etc, but it looks dirty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just capture the tableView in the blocks and call reloadData

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Destructive, title: "Delete") { (action, indexPath) in
    // delete item at indexPath
    ...
    tableView.reloadData()
}
  let share = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "Disable") { (action, indexPath) in
    // share item at indexPath
    ...
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: How could I miss this... I'll go get a coffre, thanks